# How to enable ESMTP in postfix server

Tags: postfix, smtp, email-server

I have setup a posfix mailserver and some of the messages (sent from Microsoft exchange online) are rejected with below error.

`SMTPSEND.BareLinefeedsAreIllegal; message contains bare linefeeds, which cannot be sent via DATA and receiving system does not support BDAT`

I found a Miscrosoft forum that asked to enable ESMTP in receiveing server but I couldn't find a way of doing it. Or based on the above error is there a way to support BDAT in postfix servers?

Update:
The output of the `nc -C mx.xxxxxxx.com 25 <<<$'EHLO example.com\nQUIT\n'`

```
220 localhost ESMTP Postfix
250-localhost
250-PIPELINING
250-SIZE 1024000000
250-VRFY
250-ETRN
250-STARTTLS
250-ENHANCEDSTATUSCODES
250-8BITMIME
250 DSN
221 2.0.0 Bye
```

Comment: Have you had look on this? http://www.postfix.org/BDAT_README.html

Comment: Yes, it says BDAT is enabled by default and can be disabled. But I haven't disabled it in my server so not sure what's the exact issue.

Comment: Are you running postfix behind some sort of intercepting firewall? ([edit] your question to show your servers greeting, e.g. the output of the command `nc -C mx.example.com 25 <<<$'EHLO example.com\nQUIT\n'`)

Comment: Added the output.

Comment: It looks like you didn't actually connect to your server, or it is seriously misconfigured. Postfix answered as 'localhost', which should never happen. Check your server's hostname.